# Can gold be found in middle range of the Himalayas like in Himachal Pradesh mountains or rivers above 3500 m that come directly from the glaciers?

Tags: mountains, rivers

Can gold be found in the middle range of the Himalayas like in the Himachal Pradesh mountains or rivers above 3500 metres that come directly from the glaciers? Such as in the river banks of the Satluj river or mountains that are situated 3500 m above and rivers that comes directly from the glaciers in the upper Shimla and Kinnaur?

Comment: Googling "Himalayan placer gold" returns numerous results.

Comment: https://emerginghimachal.hp.gov.in/miningstone/survay_docs/Mineral_Resources_of_Himachal_Pradesh.pdf is a comprehensive summary of mineral resources in Himachal Pradesh compiled by geologists in the local government.

Answer (score 3):

Gold can be found in various geological settings, including mountainous regions such as the Himalayas. In the middle range of the Himalayas, particularly in areas like Himachal Pradesh, there is potential for gold occurrences. While I don't have access to real-time data, it is known that gold has been found in some parts of Himachal Pradesh and the surrounding regions.

Glacial rivers originating from the Himalayan glaciers can carry eroded material, including gold particles, downstream. The gold deposits in these rivers often form as a result of weathering and erosion of gold-bearing rocks and mineral veins upstream.

Areas such as the river banks of the Satluj river and mountains situated above 3500 meters in upper Shimla and Kinnaur have the potential to contain gold deposits. These regions have a history of gold mining and exploration activities due to the presence of favorable geological conditions.

It's worth noting that gold deposits are typically found in specific geological formations and structures, such as quartz veins or placer deposits. The presence and abundance of gold can vary significantly within a region, and detailed geological surveys, prospecting, and exploration activities are required to assess the potential for economic gold deposits in specific locations.